# Jquery - Avoid code repeating

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering if I could simplify this kind of code :

```
$(this).formWizard( {
    onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        ## My code
    }, 
    onLast: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        ## My code
    },
    ...
})
```

to something like this or else :

```
$(this).formWizard( {
    onNext, onLast: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        ## My code
    }
})
```

I know there are other solutions, but is there a way to group several events to one function ?

Sorry for my English.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MelanciaUK No, that has nothing to do with code review. The OP is asking if something is possible, not if his/her code is good.

Comment: @MelanciaUK no, this is not functional, runnable code. It would be a waste of code-review time.

Comment: Got it. Retracting my vote to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not save the function into a variable?

```
var myHandler = function(tab, navigation, index) {
      // My code
};

$(this).formWizard( {
    onNext: myHandler,
    onLast: myHandler
})
```

Comment: i would sugest this approach too. but i think the OP wants to know how to group those events

Comment: @FelipeSkinner What do you mean by "group"? Only if they fire together?

Comment: i think he wants to do something like "onNext, onLast: myHandler". i know that the result will be the same, but maybe he wants it for personal knowledge

Comment: @wumm : this is what I was thinking about, but I thought there was another syntax like I wrote. Thank you.

Comment: @FelipeSkinner : you're right, for my knowledge too ^^
But I expected more like "onNext, onLast: function()" to avoid using a variable. Althought, result is the same and satisfy me.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not permitted by javascript syntax. The smartest will be to create a function and call it on the two events, as suggested by @wumm.